# getting "comma-separated list near 'xx.yy' invalid" with dbms_utility.comma_to_table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, split

I have string like this: str:='ac_Abc.88,ac_Abc.99,ac_Abc.77'. I need to get first element after splitting with comma(,). So im using using like this:

```
str VARCHAR2(500);
dbms_utility.comma_to_table
      ( list   => regexp_replace(str,'(^|,)','\1')
      , tablen => l_count
      , tab    => l_array
     );
```

I'm getting following error:

```
ORA-20001: comma-separated list invalid near bc.88
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 239
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 272
```

But if i have string like this, str:='ac_Abc88,ac_Abc99,ac_Abc77', the same method working fine and giving me expected results.

So i guess there is something need to be corrected to consider "." as regular character. Can you please suggest how can i solve this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [**How to split comma delimited string into rows**](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/)

**1. REGEXP_SUBSTR approach**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'ac_Abc.88,ac_Abc.99,ac_Abc.77' str FROM dual)
  3  SELECT regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+',1,level) str
  4  FROM DATA
  5    CONNECT BY regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
  6  /

STR
-----------------------------
ac_Abc.88
ac_Abc.99
ac_Abc.77

SQL>
```

**2. XML approach**

```
SQL> SELECT EXTRACT (VALUE (d), '//row/text()').getstringval () str
  2  FROM
  3    (SELECT XMLTYPE ( '<rows><row>'
  4      || REPLACE ('ac_Abc.88,ac_Abc.99,ac_Abc.77', ',', '</row><row>')
  5      || '</row></rows>' ) AS xmlval
  6    FROM DUAL
  7    ) x,
  8    TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (x.xmlval, '/rows/row'))) d
  9  /

STR
--------------------
ac_Abc.88
ac_Abc.99
ac_Abc.77
```

**3. Table function**

```
SQL> CREATE TYPE test_type
  2  AS
  3    TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100)
  4  /

Type created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  FUNCTION comma_to_table(
  3      p_list IN VARCHAR2)
  4    RETURN test_type
  5  AS
  6    l_string VARCHAR2(32767) := p_list || ',';
  7    l_comma_index PLS_INTEGER;
  8    l_index PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  9    l_tab test_type     := test_type();
 10  BEGIN
 11    LOOP
 12      l_comma_index := INSTR(l_string, ',', l_index);
 13      EXIT
 14    WHEN l_comma_index = 0;
 15      l_tab.EXTEND;
 16      l_tab(l_tab.COUNT) := SUBSTR(l_string, l_index, l_comma_index - l_index);
 17      l_index            := l_comma_index                           + 1;
 18    END LOOP;
 19    RETURN l_tab;
 20  END comma_to_table;
 21  /

Function created.

SQL> sho err
No errors.
SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(comma_to_table('ac_Abc.88,ac_Abc.99,ac_Abc.77'))
  2  /

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ac_Abc.88
ac_Abc.99
ac_Abc.77

SQL>
```

**4. Pipelined Function**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2    FUNCTION comma_to_table(
  3        p_list IN VARCHAR2)
  4      RETURN test_type PIPELINED
  5    AS
  6      l_string LONG := p_list || ',';
  7      l_comma_index PLS_INTEGER;
  8      l_index PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  9    BEGIN
 10      LOOP
 11        l_comma_index := INSTR(l_string, ',', l_index);
 12        EXIT
 13      WHEN l_comma_index = 0;
 14        PIPE ROW ( SUBSTR(l_string, l_index, l_comma_index - l_index) );
 15        l_index := l_comma_index                           + 1;
 16      END LOOP;
 17      RETURN;
 18    END comma_to_table;
 19    /

Function created.

SQL> sho err
No errors.
SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(comma_to_table('ac_Abc.88,ac_Abc.99,ac_Abc.77'))
  2  /

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ac_Abc.88
ac_Abc.99
ac_Abc.77
```

Comment: A beautiful demonstration of the default "greediness" of Oracle's regexps.

Comment: @nop77svk, the famous `comma_to_table` by Tom Kyte is also a good option.

Comment: Thanks, might have a look at it, although I usually have these small things coded myself.

Comment: @nop77svk, I added a demo in my answer.

Comment: Your demo uses the `dbms_utility.comma_to_table()` which is the one that does not work in the original question because of the dots (`.`) and the digits.

Comment: Try the demo with `'THIS.1S,4.COMMA,5EPARATED.5TRING'` instead of `'THIS,IS,A,COMMA,SEPARATED,STRING'`.

Comment: Yup, need to write own utility.

Comment: Yes, that's the "beauty" of some of the Oracle's supplied packages - they are of no use in general cases ... as stated in my answer above. :-)

Comment: Thanks Lalit. Your solution worked as expected. Unable to upvote your solution due to less repution.

Comment: @kaluva, I have added more examples. Use them as required.

Comment: @LalitKumarB, thank you very much. Will definitely go through your examples. Hurray, my rep also increased ans so able to upvote your solution. :)

Answer (score 6):

It is because ([Oracle doc reference](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_util.htm#ARPLS73224))

> **COMMA_TO_TABLE Procedures**
>
> These procedures converts a comma-delimited list of names into a
>   PL/SQL table of names. The second version supports fully-qualified
>   attribute names.

A "name" referred to here is a valid Oracle (DB object) identifier, for which all naming rules apply. `ac_Abc.88` is not a valid name, because in Oracle you can't have an identifier starting with a digit.

To resolve your problem with parsing strings of comma-delimited values, use the solution of Lalit Kumar B's.

Comment: Yes Lalit's solution worked. Unable to upvote due to less reputation. Could you please upvote on behalf of me.. :)