# parse comma separated string in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Hi I have a comma separated GUI ID's which I need to pass to procedure and there I will parse. Below procedure is working till 30 character lenght, my GUI ID is 36 character length, so its giving error. Can some one please help me.
        My commaSeparatedString = '"06b7930e-293f-6604-e053-2176a8c09440","06b7930e-293f-6604-e053-2176a8c09440"';

I need to pass commaSeparatedString  to procedure and get o/p as 
        06b7930e-293f-6604-e053-2176a8c09440 and 
        06b7930e-293f-6604-e053-2176a8c09440
Kindly please alter my procedure. Thanks in advance

```
create or replace 
        procedure PROC_ASSIGN_SUBSETS_TESTING(
        subsetIdString in varchar2,
        userId in varchar2,
        type in varchar2
        ) is

    subsetIdArray STR_ARRAY;
    subsetId varchar(255);
    shopCount number;
    shopId varchar(255);
    userAccessId varchar(255);

       ltab_lname dbms_utility.lname_array;
       ln_len     BINARY_INTEGER;
    BEGIN
    dbms_utility.comma_to_table(list   =>subsetIdString
                                  ,tablen => ln_len
                                  ,tab    => ltab_lname);
      FOR i IN 1 .. ln_len LOOP
          dbms_output.put_line('element ' || i || ' is ' || replace(ltab_lname(i),'"'));     
       END LOOP;
    END;
```

Comment: The 30 char restriction is because `dbms_utility.comma_to_table` with the accompanying `dbms_utility.lname_array` is designed for a comma separated string of *Oracle object names* - and such names are by definition maximum 30 characters.

Comment: @Kim, is there any other way to parse this comma separated string??

Comment: @PratapA.K, you can use plain `SQL` to achieve this, see my answer. Or, else, you could write your own `function`. See the other techniques in the link I posted in my answer.

Comment: @KimBergHansen - type lname_array can store upto 4000 chars only name_array is limited to 30 chars, so it should work in that case since the code uses only lname array

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_util.htm#i1004907

`lname_array`

TYPE lname_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000) index by BINARY_INTEGER;
Lists of Long NAME should be stored here, it includes fully qualified attribute names.

`name_array`

TYPE name_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
Lists of NAME should be stored here.

Comment: @arunb2w It would have helped if Pratap had included the error. The error is `PLS-00114: identifier '06b7930e-293f-6604-e053-2176a8' too long` . So yes, you are correct that `lname_array` can contain longer elements since it can contain fully qualified object identifiers. But since the function is designed for Oracle object identifiers, it seems like it is checking for validity of the object identifiers in the comma separated string. And therefore it is not a good idea to use `dbms_utility.comma_to_table` as a *generic* comma separated string parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following techniques :

**REGEXP_SUBSTR approach**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2      SELECT q'["06b7930e-293f-6604-e053-2176a8c09440","06b7930e-293f-6604-e053-2176a8c09440"]' str
  3    FROM dual)
  4  SELECT regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+',1,level) str
  5    FROM DATA
  6  CONNECT BY regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
  7  /

STR
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
"06b7930e-293f-6604-e053-2176a8c09440"
"06b7930e-293f-6604-e053-2176a8c09440"

SQL>
```

I have answered a similar question here [getting "comma-separated list near 'xx.yy' invalid" with dbms_utility.comma_to_table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273042/getting-comma-separated-list-near-xx-yy-invalid-with-dbms-utility-comma-to-t) using other approaches like **XML, table function, pipelined function**.

Answer (score 2):

type `lname_array` can store upto 4000 chars only ,
`name_array` is limited to 30 chars, so it should work in that case since the code uses only lname array.

[Oracle reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_util.htm#i1004907)

`lname_array  TYPE lname_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000) index by BINARY_INTEGER`;

Lists of Long NAME should be stored here, it includes fully qualified attribute names.

```
name_array  TYPE name_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

Lists of NAME should be stored here.

Also, Instead of calling  dbms_utility.comma_to_table you can use the below query to convert ',' seperated values to table

```
 select replace(
regexp_substr('"06b7930e-293f-6604-e053-2176a8c09440",
"06b7930e-293f-6604-e053-2176a8c09440"','[^,]+',1,level),'"')
from dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE('"06b7930e-293f-6604-e053-2176a8c09440",
"06b7930e-293f-6604-e053-2176a8c09440"' , '[^,]+')) + 1;
```