# Perform a query with a variable as subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query like this:

```sql
select * from SOURCE
where A = 'a'
and B in (
  select SOMECOLUMN from VERY_LONG_QUERY 
  WHERE SOMECHECK = 'some check'
)
```

I'd like convert the above query to a statement PL/SQL like this:

```sql
veryLongQueryVar := 'select SOMECOLUMN from VERY_LONG_QUERY WHERE SOMECHECK = ''some check'' ' 

select * from SOURCE
where A = 'a'
and B in veryLongQueryVar
```

How it is possible?

Comment: what do you expect by doing that?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? You're looking at dynamic sql if part of the query needs to be generated on-the-fly. In general, static sql is better (more maintainable, less prone to sql injection, etc)

Comment: This sounds like dynamic SQL and you would use `execute immediate`.  It also doesn't sound like a very good idea.  You are probably trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: My idea was to split the 2 queries, in order to be more clear and readable for other developers. Also, I did an example with only one subquery but in my real case I have 3 nested queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve something similar with [`WITH` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6):

```
with veryLongQueryVar as
 (select SOMECOLUMN from VERY_LONG_QUERY WHERE SOMECHECK = 'some check')
select * from SOURCE
where A = 'a'
 and B in (select SOMECOLUMN from veryLongQueryVar)
```

You can also use `SELECT INTO` to select your very long query results into variable (of type table of something) and the [use `table` to pass it into IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28737346/pass-value-stored-in-a-pl-sql-variable-into-an-in-clause). But that would result in two separate queries and it seems you want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion what you can do.

You store the values from the long query in a collection and use that in another select.

```
declare
  TYPE my_collection IS TABLE OF SOMECOLUMN%type
      INDEX BY number;
  tab my_collection ;
  rec SOURCE%rowtype;
begin
  select SOMECOLUMN 
  bulk collect into tab 
  from VERY_LONG_QUERY 
  WHERE SOMECHECK = 'some check';


  select * into rec 
    from SOURCE
   where A = 'a'
     and B in (select column_value from table(tab);
end;
```

you can also create a dynamic SQL string.

```
declare
  TYPE cur IS REF CURSOR;
  my_cur   cur;
  veryLongQueryVar  varchar2(32000);
begin
  veryLongQueryVar := 'select SOMECOLUMN from VERY_LONG_QUERY WHERE SOMECHECK = ''some check'' ' 

  veryLongQueryVar  := 'select * from SOURCE
                        where A = ''a''
                        and B in ('||veryLongQueryVar ||')'

  open my_cur for veryLongQueryVar  ;
  ....

end;
```

Comment: I got this error: `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "OPEN" when expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.`